# OleDbDataAdapter.Fill doesn't work when checkpoints are enabled

Tags: ssis

We faced a weird issue this week related to "OleDbDataAdapter.Fill" method in a script task. We are storing a query result in an Object variable and this data is used inside a script task. When checkpoints are enabled, we are not able to read the object variable using OleDbDataAdapter. When checkpoint is disabled - the code works fine.

Any workarounds for this issue ?

Regards,

Kumar

Answer (score 0):

One cannot read variables from a blob object, which is what you would use to fill the OleDbDataAdapter using a debugger. You can however try to look through the results of the datatable to which you assign the value once that is initiated in the loop.

You can check this link that gives a very good breakdown of how to loop through object - https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2015/04/20/using-the-ssis-object-variable-as-a-data-flow-source/

In the script code that is pasted, you can put the debugger across foreach loop and then iterate and see through the results. This can be done

Comment: I guess you misread my question, I am able to read data from Object variable in a script task using OleDbDataAdapter.Fill method. The issue is when checkpoint is enable and this stops working.

Comment: When you say stops working, does the package execution halt or fail? Can you post a psuedo code or the code where you think the problem is occuring as an edit to your question?